# Is there a SELECT WHERE... IN equivalent in Xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am new to Xquery and having a hard time dealing with this problem. 
Basically, my current XML file's structure is like this:

```
<root>
   <a>
      <aid>XX</aid>
      ...
   </a>
   <a>
      <aid>xx</aid>
      ...
   </a>
   <b>
      <bid>xx</bid>
      ...
   </b>
   <b>
      <bid>xx</bid>
      ...
   </b>
...
</root>
```

What I am trying to get is the information of the b elements whose "bid" **do not equal to any** "aid" from the a elements. 
I tried to do it like this. First I let a variable to hold the aid:

`let $aid := (xpath to the aid elements)`

then I tried to do something like the "SELECT WHERE IN" from traditional sql. namely:

`for $b in (xpath to b elements)`

`where $b/bid != $aid`   (I tried to achieve the NOT IN effect)

`return $b/(infomation)`

But the problem is I can't find the right method to do this. I also tried

`where $e/bid != $aid[*]`

, it didn't work either. So am I on a wrong track? Is there anyway to achieve this in Xquery(1.0)? Or is there other methods to get the required infomation?

Comment: Please post the specific code you're having problems with, fitted to the input provided. Also give current and expected output. Maybe have a look at [ask] and [hot to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the b elements whose "bid" do not equal to any "aid" from the a elements.

The most direct way of doing that is

```
for $b in //b
where not(exists(//a[aid = $b/bid]))
return $b
```

Comment: Nice solution, though I'm wondering: is the exists() strictly necessary?

Comment: Simply effective! I was too restricted by the "where (not) in" thinking and wasn't aware the NOT() function.   Also, I tested removing the "exists()" like JKesMc9tqlQe9M mentioned. It's okay to remove that.

Comment: The exists() isn't necessary but I feel it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @michaelkay thanks for confirming about the exists() -- I agree it makes the code more readable, but just wanted to verify that was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if following XPath approach is usable in your setting. Following XPath

```
//b/bid[not(./text() = //a/aid/text())]/text()
```

when applied to the example XML

```
<root>
  <a>
    <aid>XX</aid>
  </a>
  <a>
    <aid>YY</aid>
  </a>
  <b>
    <bid>XX</bid>
  </b>
  <b>
    <bid>YY</bid>
  </b>
  <b>
    <bid>ZZ</bid> 
  </b>
</root>
```

returns `ZZ`.
As you mentioned that you would like to get all information from the `b` nodes which `bid` value does not equal any `aid` value, I assume that you have more child nodes for the `a` and `b` nodes. To get the matching b nodes together with all child nodes following XPath

```
//b[bid[not(./text() = //a/aid/text())]]
```

when applied to the extended example XML

```
<root>
  <a>
    <aid>XX</aid>
    <more>more a XX</more>
  </a>
  <a>
    <aid>YY</aid>
    <more>more a YY</more>
  </a>
  <b>
    <bid>XX</bid>
    <more>more b XX</more>
  </b>
  <b>
    <bid>YY</bid>
    <more>more b YY</more> 
  </b>
  <b>
    <bid>ZZ</bid>
    <more>more b ZZ</more>
  </b>
</root>
```

returns

```
<b>
  <bid>ZZ</bid>
  <more>more b ZZ</more>
</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator actually does a membership test in XQuery.

Thus,

```
a = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux')
```

actually tests whether `a` is *any of* `foo`, `bar`, `baz` or `qux`.

So -- it's just the standard equality operator used as an equivalent to `WHERE IN`, giving it a sequence on one side.

Comment: I see. Now I guess my early mistake was using "!=".   I tried        "where a[aid != $b/bid]"    But I should use "where not(//a[aid = $b/bid])"